# how i can hide the line under tap?

Tags: html, css

i have this navbar, when i hover on tag  the result is :
[when hover on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC6gY.jpg)

i try to make it like that , but i can't  :
[i need like this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHLBo.jpg)

.

```
menu-large-hover {
    position: static !important;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Paste your current `HTML` and your `CSS` here

Comment: add some html code

Comment: you can see it on website , http://www.shopaski.com/

Comment: Your sub menu container taking top border there.

Comment: look the pic number 2 ,, i need the top border in sub menu ,, but under the tap i need hide the line ,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add/edit below classes in your css

```
 .menu-large-hover a#font-mega {
     background: #fff;
     z-index: 200000;
     padding: 16px 27px
}
    .navbar-nav > li {
    margin: 0 9px 0 0;
    height: 51px
}
```